# Django Use multiple redis for caching

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

I have a Django project and i am using [django-redis](https://pypi.org/project/django-redis/) where I want to implement different types of caching,

1. Caching search query
2. Caching static pages
3. Cache user Data (eg: online status)

I can add different prefix for different kind of caching, but I want to use different redis server for all the different caching I have.
I couldn't find anything on the docs how to do this

My current settings

```
CACHES = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://localhost:6379/1",
    "OPTIONS": {
        "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
        "IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS": True,
    },
    "KEY_PREFIX": "db_cache",
}
```

}

What I would want

```
CACHES = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://localhost:6379/",
    "OPTIONS": {
        "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
    },
    "KEY_PREFIX": "db_cache",
},
'static_page': {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://localhost:6378/",
    "OPTIONS": {
        "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
        "IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS": True,
    },
    "KEY_PREFIX": "db_cache",
},
'user_data': {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://localhost:6377/",
    "OPTIONS": {
        "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        "PARSER_CLASS": "redis.connection.HiredisParser",
    },
    "KEY_PREFIX": "db_cache",
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a redis instance running on each of these ports?

Comment: Yes i have these redis servers running, while the question has nothing to do with redis server it can be a Local Memory Cache. or dummy cache, it should work for everything.

Comment: Well that should be possible, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: i dont know where to start currently i am using cache.set() and cache.get() but it is saving in the default database how do i specify database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the answer while looking for something else

Instead of using

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('hello', 'bye')
cache.get('hello')
```

which stores the data in the default caching Use something like this

```
from django.core.cache import caches
c = caches['static_page']
c.set('hello', 'bye')
c.get('hello')
```

It is such a small thing that most of the document don't mention it separately, and you might miss it when going through the documentation.